# communicating binary files from javascript to flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, externalinterface

I am using flash External Interface to send media files from javascript to actionscript. However, sending the binary as a string causes unexpected problems. Presence of certain characters in the binary file causes the string to be received as null. One such character was ﷡ .

I tried using btoa() on the file but it failed with "invalid characters" within the js itself.

I have a flash application which need to make http calls with range request header. Since range header is not allowed in flash, I am using external interface on javascript but then stuck here.

Comment: How do you encode the string? You could use some safe ways like Base64, but the information could get pretty big (not sure if there is any limitation)..

Comment: As I said, I used btoa() which failed with error: Invalid characters. I also used an alternative base64 js library which did a toUtf() function before the actual encoding. However, I couldn't regenerate the actual data in actionscript.

Comment: As said in MDN: `Please note that this is not suitable for raw Unicode strings!`.. Maybe this: http://jsbase64.codeplex.com/

Comment: That is what I referred as alternative base64 library. If you note it's source code, it calls toUtf() function before encoding converting a 100kb chunk to ~255kb. However in as3, a simple base64 deocode gave 199kb which on passing through a fromUtf() function (which I ported from the jsbase64 to as3) resulted in ~143kb. I couldn't get the original data back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to write a few scripts to do this job. They basically encode the javascript array buffer into ascii characters and then decode them in actionscript.
I am not sure how efficient these are.

https://gist.github.com/vibhavsinha/11344013